# Customize layout div, Fixed Div but responsive size of browser, Responsive Text

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Note : I'm using various link css n js so it's little complicated for me..

The end user request is :

1. Tab menu with saveral ajax progress, one of it is "container div"
2. There is line to border the result of container div
3. there is four type of box inside container div,
4. Type a:33% form width,b:67%,c:100%,d:67%+2row all of it is fixed.
   (1 row could fill with 3 type of a, or just type b and type a, or kind..)
5. The container of each div is various text, with title,meta description, description, button.(The container can't pass the div, only cat words not character, if in small size the container must follow its div)
6. At the end of all div there is one button in bottom.

Progress:

1. done
2. done
3. done
4. done
5. **Stuck**
6. done

Sample but just sample, just for imagine..

1. [Pick html 5 and look the list of news or kind of that](http://kopatheme.com/demo/great-news-wordpress-theme/)
2. [3 box with almost like my want but](http://www.paul-rand.com/)

The text is could broke the row, i want the text cut in words if it didn' fit and i won't resize of text size. but it always crash with layout of div.

Thanks for any help..

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: morning,, sry late reply,, https://jsfiddle.net/g96c1g3L/1/ chek resize of it. just focus on problem nomber 5.

Comment: If i have a lot text/a little long title/kind, there is always crash another div if i resize to small size of browser,,

Comment: Check out the updated fiddle at: https://jsfiddle.net/g96c1g3L/2/. If that does not meet your requirements, then please be as clear as possible with your expectations and I'll be happy to help.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g96c1g3L/3/ i'm update too, for repair the border. ok, then its still, if they "same type", i want the "height of border is same" even the text is different, so the text is cut in each words. it's also should works on small size of browser..

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What else is missing?

Comment: http://i61.tinypic.com/2e4gn09.png just wannt height of black line is same, even the size of browser is different..

Comment: The height of the black line is exactly the same!?!?!

Comment: nope, in the image if the size of broser is small, the height/distance from first div to second div is different..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/g96c1g3L/4/

```
function resizeRowHeight() {
    var maxHeight = 0;
    $('div[class^="col-sm-"]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
            maxHeight = $(this).height();
        }
    });
    $('div[class^="col-sm-"]').each(function() {
        $(this).css('min-height', maxHeight + 'px');
    });
}
```

***Updated fiddle***

https://jsfiddle.net/g96c1g3L/5/

Comment: Can you please send me another screenshot?

Comment: http://i57.tinypic.com/qqycmx.png left side if i resize more bigger, other div is dissapeared, right side is if i run again after resize is nicer,,, sory if so much trouble..